# How do I change all plain text files to .txt files in a directory? Is there such a command?

Tags: command-line, files, file-type

I have tried `rename` command but didn't succeed.

Comment: What files are in this directory? The output of ls would be useful. If all files are simply text files with no extensions in place the following would suffice: `for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done`

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks a lot! It worked just as I wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your directory is filled *only* with simple text files the most direct way to give *all* files and extension of .txt is to open a Terminal window in the directory and run the following command:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done
```

You have to love the command line :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to do this.

**First**, *the safe way* will create a copy of the files with the txt extension and will preserve the original files:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(file * | grep text | grep -v "\.txt\|exec" | sed 's/\:.*$//g'); do cp -- "$i" "$i".txt; done
```

**Alternatively**, the following method will not preserve the original files:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(file * | grep text | grep -v "\.txt\|exec" | sed 's/\:.*$//g'); do mv -- "$i" "$i".txt; done
```

---

Both of these methods use the `file` command to determine which files are ASCII text files. Then, `grep` filters the results to only include the files that are "text". Next, `grep -v "\.txt\|exec"` excludes the files that already contain the ".txt" file extension and shell script executables and `sed` isolates the file names to give us a clean list of the files.

The first method uses the `cp` command to create a *copy* of each file with the ".txt" extension.

The second method uses the `mv` command to *move* each filename to a new name with the ".txt" extension.

I also used an [input field separator](https://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/bash-shell-script-for-loop-iterate-blank-spaces-in-file) at the beginning of the loop to include files with blank spaces.

Additionally, it won't work properly if a filename contains a newline or colons.

Comment: @pLumo The original files are preserved so yeah it is safe even if you don't get the desired results. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is much better now, thanks :-) It will still choke on newline in file names. Might be okay sometimes, but may be worth mentioning...

Comment: @pLumo Yeah, well your answer doesn't exclude bash scripts and shell script executables :)

Comment: That is true ... a bash script is a text file imo ^^ In general, I think it is a bad idea to give text files a .txt exension ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the

```bsh
file -i NameofFileGoesHere
```

command.

> [File man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)

See if you discover a pattern 
Sample Output:

```bsh
file.mp4: application/octet-stream; charset=binary                                                       
filenumplayer1: inode/x-empty; charset=binary                                                          
foobar.ogg: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

For some files it returns:

```bsh
headstart.save: text/x-shellscript; charset=us-ascii
```

You are looking for files marked "ascii"
But they could be Really any kind of file. Especially if it is a file that was not created by you. It would not be a good idea to rename it.

But if all files are indeed personal files. 
Based on the above info I would try the following script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in * 
do
#Looking for the string us-ascii hence this command
whatis=$(file --mime "$f" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
if [[ $whatis == "us-ascii" ]]
then
mv "$f" "$f.txt"
fi
done
```

This is only to answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

This will move all text-files in current directory to `.txt` if they not already have that extension.
You can change or remove `-maxdepth 1` to make it recursive.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
  -exec grep -Iq . {} \; \
  -exec sh -c '
      test "$1" != "${1%.txt}.txt" \
      && mv -i -- "$1" "${1%.txt}.txt"
  ' find-sh {} \;
```

`grep -Iq . {}` will let `find` skip binary files ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767396/linux-command-how-to-find-only-text-files)).
You don't really need that `test` part, but then, `mv` will throw an error message.

---

Alternative if you want it **recursive**:

```
grep -rIlZ . . \
| xargs -0 -I{} sh -c '
      test "$1" != "${1%.txt}.txt" \
      && mv -i -- "$1" "${1%.txt}.txt"
  ' xargs-sh {}
```